# How to change bar color acording to label value in chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to use bars in chartjs and I need all bars to be in one color, and just one in the middle to be of other color. It would be the best if I could create value range according to which the specific color would be used.

http://s24.postimg.org/4jg17tm5h/graf.png

I have painted this one bar manually with this command

```
myLine.datasets[0].bars[50].fillColor = "red";
```

but I need it to be automatically, to pick one value and to chose color by its limits. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used part of your solution and solved problem

```
        for (var i = 0; i < myLine.datasets[0].bars.length; i++) {
        console.log(myLine.datasets[0].bars[i].value);
        if(myLine.datasets[0].bars[i].value < 10) {
            myLine.datasets[0].bars[i].fillColor = "red";
        } else if (myLine.datasets[0].bars[i].value > 20) {
            myLine.datasets[0].bars[i].fillColor = "yellow";
        }
    }
```

This is what I need, thanks, I didn't know how to access values of bars.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `getBarsAtEvent` method in the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-prototype-methods).

Here is an example of how you could use it, though you will likely have to modify this to your specific needs:

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(evt) {
    var bars = chart.getBarsAtEvent(evt);
    for (var i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
        setColor(bars[i]);
    }
};

function setColor(bar) {
    if (bar.value < 10) {
        bar.fillColor = "red";
    } else if (bar.value < 20) {
        bar.fillColor = "yellow";
    } else {
        bar.fillColor = "green";
   }
}
```